# How add combined field at module like `refers_to`

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

Good day.
I want to add field that should contain link to related some module item, but modules can changes. 
For example, this field that I need should be at Accounts and should contains links to Calls, Emails, Meetings etc objects. And I can choose module and object like [image: combined field with selector to choose module and subpanel view get choose modules's item]

How to do this field?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*[note: This was written before the question was tagged with 'suitecrm'. While SuiteCRM is based on SugarCRM CE 6.5, there are many  differences between their current versions, so not everything stated below might apply to SuiteCRM.]*</sup>

That field type is called `flex relate` field.
In regular Sugar each module can only have **one** field of that type.
It is saved in the database as `parent_type` (containing the linked module's name) and `parent_id` (containing the linked record's id).

The modules you can choose from are defined by the *dropdown list* `parent_type_display` and can be changed there.
(The list's values are supposed to be the modules'  *technical* name as seen in the URL and database fields; its labels can be anything).

If you want different lists available in different modules, you can do that via code by overriding the list name in the `options` attribute of each modules `parent_type` field's VarDefs.

Instructions on how to create flex relate fields in Module Builder and Studio can be found in the official documentation: https://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Studio_and_Module_Builder/Creating_a_Flex_Relate_Field/